# Count X Amount of Working Days from Date Entered

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

I have a Microsoft Access database where the user is required to enter a `Date Opened:` value.  Once entered, this triggers a calculation in another field, `Deadline (25 WD):`.  This works via the following function in the latter field:

```
=DateAdd("d",25,[Date opened])
```

What I want to do, however, is to count 25 **working** days from the date entered in `Date Opened:`.  I have a table `holidays` which contains a list of UK holidays up until 2020.

How can I merge to two, so-to-speak, in order to produce a valid `Deadline (25 WD):` value which does not count any of the dates listed in `holidays`?

For example, if the date entered is 01/01/2015, then the function would count 25 working days from 01/01/2015, meaning that it would exclude all weekends and any bank holidays that fall within that period and **the resulting date value in the field `Deadline (25 WD)` will also be a working day (i.e. not a weekend or bank holiday)**.

Comment: (I think) You count the number of holidays between `Date Opened` and `Date Opened + 25 days` and add the result to `Date Opened + 25 days`.

Comment: Yes, I think that might do it.  Although the problem is that I would also need to figure out a way of calculating the weekends, too.  Unless, of course, I add the weekends into my `holidays` table.

Comment: I disagree - it is not off-topic and is very much the same question with no extra requirements. Asking a new question would almost certainly constitute a duplicate as the requirements will remain the same, and the only possible outcome is an answer spread over 2 questions. After some investigation it appears that it was not actually resolved after all as the resulting value in the field still sometimes falls on a bank holiday or weekend and this is only something that could have come up through using the system.  If an answer (updated or new) resolves this, then I will accept accordingly.

Comment: Okay in that case, adding 25 working days to 01 Jan 2015, will be 06 Feb 2015 which is Friday. Say it is 26 days, then you would want 09 Feb 2015? If that's the case, please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need a UDF to get you through this. Something like,

```
Function addWorkDays(addNumber As Long, Date2 As Date) As Date
'********************
'Code Courtesy of
'  Paul Eugin
'********************

    Dim finalDate As Date
    Dim i As Long, tmpDate As Date
    tmpDate = Date2
    i = 1
    Do While i <= addNumber
        If Weekday(tmpDate) <> 1 And Weekday(tmpDate) <> 7 And _
            DCount("*", "tbl_BankHolidays", "bankDate = " & Format(tmpDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")) = 0 Then i = i + 1
        tmpDate = DateAdd("d", 1, tmpDate)
    Loop

    Do While Weekday(tmpDate) = 1 Or Weekday(tmpDate) = 7 Or _
        DCount("*", "tbl_BankHolidays", "bankDate = " & Format(tmpDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")) <> 0
        tmpDate = DateAdd("d", 1, tmpDate)
    Loop

    addWorkDays = tmpDate
End Function
```

So, when you add 25 days to a date, it will skip all weekends and bank holidays stored in your table - `tbl_BankHolidays`.

```
? addWorkDays(25, Date())
  25/06/2015
```

Hope this helps !

**EDIT:** I have added another loop to see if the end date falls on a bank holiday or weekend, if it does it will add one more day until it reaches a weekday.

Comment: I've spotted a problem - the date that the field contains sometimes is a weekend and I want it to exclude weekends, with the result being a working day also - is this possible?  I was not aware of this initially but after testing the system further and more intensely, this problem has arisen.  I will also update the existing question to include this. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the update, PaulFrancis. I have to disagree again, as I did not have a new problem - a new aspect of the initial problem had surfaced once I had implemented your answer and having an answer split between two questions regarding the same issue is somewhat counter-intuitive.  However, your updated answer works exactly as hoped for and for that reason, I have re-accepted your (updated) answer.  Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: Glad to hear you have it resolved. I have retracted my vote. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
Public Function DateAddWorkdays( _
    ByVal lngNumber As Long, _
    ByVal datDate As Date, _
    Optional ByVal booWorkOnHolidays As Boolean) _
    As Date

'   Adds lngNumber of workdays to datDate.
'   2014-10-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH

    ' Calendar days per week.
    Const clngWeekdayCount  As Long = 7
    ' Workdays per week.
    Const clngWeekWorkdays  As Long = 5
    ' Average count of holidays per week maximum.
    Const clngWeekHolidays  As Long = 1
    ' Maximum valid date value.
    Const cdatDateRangeMax  As Date = #12/31/9999#
    ' Minimum valid date value.
    Const cdatDateRangeMin  As Date = #1/1/100#

    Dim aHolidays() As Date

    Dim lngDays     As Long
    Dim lngDiff     As Long
    Dim lngDiffMax  As Long
    Dim lngSign     As Long
    Dim datDate1    As Date
    Dim datDate2    As Date
    Dim datLimit    As Date
    Dim lngHoliday  As Long


    lngSign = Sgn(lngNumber)
    datDate2 = datDate

    If lngSign <> 0 Then
        If booWorkOnHolidays = True Then
            ' Holidays are workdays.
        Else
            ' Retrieve array with holidays between datDate and datDate + lngDiffMax.
            ' Calculate the maximum calendar days per workweek.
            lngDiffMax = lngNumber * clngWeekdayCount / (clngWeekWorkdays - clngWeekHolidays)
            ' Add one week to cover cases where a week contains multiple holidays.
            lngDiffMax = lngDiffMax + Sgn(lngDiffMax) * clngWeekdayCount
            datDate1 = DateAdd("d", lngDiffMax, datDate)
            aHolidays = GetHolidays(datDate, datDate1)
        End If
        Do Until lngDays = lngNumber
            If lngSign = 1 Then
                datLimit = cdatDateRangeMax
            Else
                datLimit = cdatDateRangeMin
            End If
            If DateDiff("d", DateAdd("d", lngDiff, datDate), datLimit) = 0 Then
                ' Limit of date range has been reached.
                Exit Do
            End If

            lngDiff = lngDiff + lngSign
            datDate2 = DateAdd("d", lngDiff, datDate)
            Select Case Weekday(datDate2)
                Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
                    ' Skip weekend.
                Case Else
                    ' Check for holidays to skip.
                    ' Ignore error when using LBound and UBound on an unassigned array.
                    On Error Resume Next
                    For lngHoliday = LBound(aHolidays) To UBound(aHolidays)
                        If Err.Number > 0 Then
                            ' No holidays between datDate and datDate1.
                        ElseIf DateDiff("d", datDate2, aHolidays(lngHoliday)) = 0 Then
                            ' This datDate2 hits a holiday.
                            ' Subtract one day before adding one after the loop.
                            lngDays = lngDays - lngSign
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    lngDays = lngDays + lngSign
            End Select
        Loop
    End If

    DateAddWorkdays = datDate2

End Function

Public Function GetHolidays( _
    ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
    ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal booDesc As Boolean) _
    As Date()

'   Finds the count of holidays between datDate1 and datDate2.
'   The holidays are returned as an array of dates.
'   DAO objects are declared static to speed up repeated calls with identical date parameters.
'   2014-10-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH

    ' The table that holds the holidays.
    Const cstrTable             As String = "tblHoliday"
    ' The field of the table that holds the dates of the holidays.
    Const cstrField             As String = "HolidayDate"
    ' Constants for the arrays.
    Const clngDimRecordCount    As Long = 2
    Const clngDimFieldOne       As Long = 0

    Static dbs              As DAO.Database
    Static rst              As DAO.Recordset

    Static datDate1Last     As Date
    Static datDate2Last     As Date

    Dim adatDays()  As Date
    Dim avarDays    As Variant

    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim strDate1    As String
    Dim strDate2    As String
    Dim strOrder    As String
    Dim lngDays     As Long

    If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate1Last) <> 0 Or DateDiff("d", datDate2, datDate2Last) <> 0 Then
        ' datDate1 or datDate2 has changed since the last call.
        strDate1 = Format(datDate1, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
        strDate2 = Format(datDate2, "\#yyyy\/mm\/dd\#")
        strOrder = Format(booDesc, "\A\s\c;\D\e\s\c")

        strSQL = "Select " & cstrField & " From " & cstrTable & " " & _
            "Where " & cstrField & " Between " & strDate1 & " And " & strDate2 & " " & _
            "Order By 1 " & strOrder

        Set dbs = CurrentDb
        Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

        ' Save the current set of date parameters.
        datDate1Last = datDate1
        datDate2Last = datDate2
    End If

    lngDays = rst.RecordCount
    If lngDays = 0 Then
        ' Leave adatDays() as an unassigned array.
    Else
        ReDim adatDays(lngDays - 1)
        ' As repeated calls may happen, do a movefirst.
        rst.MoveFirst
        avarDays = rst.GetRows(lngDays)
        ' rst is now positioned at the last record.
        For lngDays = LBound(avarDays, clngDimRecordCount) To UBound(avarDays, clngDimRecordCount)
            adatDays(lngDays) = avarDays(clngDimFieldOne, lngDays)
        Next
    End If

    ' DAO objects are static.
    ' Set rst = Nothing
    ' Set dbs = Nothing

    GetHolidays = adatDays()

End Function
```